# Dota 2: Terrible fps or crashing system

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, ati, steam

I feel as if I've tried everything. `Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280]` is my gpu, and it provides terrible fps in Dota 2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

So far, I've tried:

`fgrxl` = Crappy fps. Stable around 30, jumps to 60 occasionally but overall terrible.

`fgrxl-updates` / `mesa` = Same as above. Stable but crappy fps.

`X.Org`/Open-source = Best experience. Stable 60 fps, sometimes even more. HOWEVER, this one crashes my system - i get frequent blackscreens in where I have to reboot my entire system. This happens both in Dota 2 and outside of it, and it "flickers" black constantly. Again. Terrible.

AMD catalyst manual installation has been tried. It crashes my system. I can't even boot in it without recovery mode.

So, I've tried.. Well, everything. At this point I've given up running Dota 2 on Ubuntu with an AMD gpu. Am I out of options? Sigh.